# How to make XTEXT templates case insensitive?

Tags: xtext

I have this templates.xml file to provide autocomplete using xtext. I want to make the words that invoke the template drop down to be case insensitive. how do i do that ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
<template 
        name="entity" 
      id="Keyword 'entity'"
      description="Template for entity"
      context="kw_entity"
      enabled="true"
      ports="ports">entity ${name} is
    port (
        ${ports}
    );
end ${name};
</template>
<template 
        name="architecture"
        id="Keyword 'architecture'"
        description="Template for architecture"
        context="kw_architecture"
        enabled="true" entityname="entity_name"
        declarations="declarations">architecture ${name} of ${entityname} is
    ${declarations}
begin
${cursor} 
end ${name};
</template>

</templates>
```

for example :
if the user writes "ArcH" and hit CTRL+SPACE the behavior needed to be the same as if he writes "arch" and hit CTRL+SPACE.

Comment: is your dsl caseinsensitive?

Comment: btw i cannot reproduce this with a simple Hello World example dsl.

Comment: are you sure there is nothing else in your dsl or template that prevents this (there are some changes in your dsl i dont know if you did them to censor company name etc)

Comment: sorry for the late response. I have a template.xml which I can use to add default templates for our tool. these templates are for VHDL which is a case-insensitive language. the templates are triggered when the user writes the first few chars form the keyword and hit CTRL+SPACE. I want that trigger to work regradless the case of the user chars.  I changed to the context of the file above to hide some info about the product, but the rest of the file is the same.

Comment: I think the change will not be in the XML file. I think it will be in the string matcher that matches the keywords with the associated templates (given that I want to avoid duplicate the keywords).

Comment: can you provide a complete minimal grammar, workflow and template that reproduces the issue